# C++: Calling derived specialised virtual functions within a base template class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Let's say I have the following template class:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    // Lots of functions...

    void someFunc(T obj)
    {
        // T must implement this function in order to be usable within class A.
        obj.interfaceFunc();
    }
};
```

This works fine, as the object I will use with the template class implements *interfaceFunc().*

However, if I pass a pointer to the template class then the compilation fails because the dereference syntax is incorrect. Because the template class contains a lot of other functions that I don't want to copy/paste into another partial specialisation if I can possibly help it, I have changed my class definition as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    // Lots of functions...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T* obj)
    {
        // We should never be here in the base class.
        assert(false);
    }

    void someFunc(T obj)
    {
        // Call the virtual function.
        virtualHelperFunction(&obj);
    }
};

// Partial specialisation 1
template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    // ...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T* obj)
    {
        obj->interfaceFunc();
    }
};

// Partial specialisation 2
template<typename T*>
class B : public A<T*>
{
public:
    // ...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T* obj)
    {
        obj->interfaceFunc();
    }
};
```

However, when *virtualHelperFunction()* is called, on an instance of B but when inside the *someFunc()* function of the parent A, it hits the assertion error.:

```
B<SomeObject> instance;
instance.someFunc(SomeObject());  // Assertion failure.
```

I've tried messing around with function pointers to solve this but I'm still fairly new to them, and the non-static pointer syntax confused me a bit. I'm assuming one could define a member pointer to the *virtualHelperFunction()* which is set to point to the base class version in A's constructor, but which is then overwritten in B's constructor to point to B's function. If so, would anyone be able to demonstrate the correct syntax to do this?

Thanks.

EDIT: If context is needed, the template class is an octree node which stores a hash table of type T. The interface function required is that the object can return a bounding box, in order for recursive insertion to function depending on whether the object's bounds intersect with the tree node's bounds.

https://github.com/x6herbius/crowbar/blob/qt3d-experimental/Modules/Octree/inc/worldculltreenode.h
https://github.com/x6herbius/crowbar/blob/qt3d-experimental/Modules/Octree/inc/worldculltreenode.tcc

Comment: In the second partial specialization the `virtualHelperFunction` function takes a pointer to a pointer to `T`, i.e. `T**`. Using the normal member dereference operator `->` will fail, I don't think it would even compile!

Comment: In my actual test I was anticipating needing to do that, but it didn't actually compile _until_ I switched them both to ->.

Comment: try this 
A<SomeObject> *instance =new B<SomeObject>;
instance->someFunc(SomeObject());

Comment: _However, if I pass a pointer to the template class then the compilation fails because the dereference syntax is incorrect_ ... can you actually show what you did, and what the result was? It really isn't clear what problem you're having.

Comment: Well if I passed in a pointer, the part of the class calling _obj.interfaceFunc()_ would fail because the compiler would be expecting _obj->interfaceFunc()._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems way too complicated. Why specialize the entire class if you just need one tiny bit specialized? All you need is a small utility that says "dereference this if it's a pointer, otherwise leave it alone". It could look like this:

```
template <typename T>
T& deref_if_pointer(T& t) { return t; }
template <typename T>
T& deref_if_pointer(T* t) { return *t; }

// ...
void someFunc(T obj) {
  deref_if_pointer(obj).interfaceFunc();
}
```

You can easily extend `deref_if_pointer` to various smart pointers as well; just add another overload.

Comment: Fantastic, that solved it perfectly. Thanks to everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what it is that you want to accomplish, so I'll have to guess. In what way does the following not satisfy your problem?

```
class A
{
public:
    // Lots of functions...

    void someFunc(T* obj)
    {
        // T must implement this function in order to be usable within class A.
        obj->interfaceFunc();
    }

    void someFunc(T obj)
    {
        // T must implement this function in order to be usable within class A.
        obj.interfaceFunc();
    }
};
```

Comment: To clarify, if T were an object pointer would this not become T** obj and T* obj, or am I getting the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: First question, why would T be an object pointer? Second question, does T need to be an object pointer? One more question, does the rest of the class actually depend on type T? If not, just make it a regular class with a templated member function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it that way, then you need to take a reference instead of a pointer in the first partial specialization:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    // Lots of functions...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T* obj)
    {
        // We should never be here in the base class.
        assert(false);
    }

    void someFunc(T obj)
    {
        // Call the virtual function.
        virtualHelperFunction(&obj);
    }
};

// Partial specialisation 1
template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    // ...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T& obj)
    {
        obj.interfaceFunc();
    }
};

// Partial specialisation 2
template<typename T*>
class B : public A<T*>
{
public:
    // ...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T* obj)
    {
        obj->interfaceFunc();
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this way and it compiled, but _virtualHelperFunction()_ in base class A was still called instead of the function in the specialised class. http://pastebin.com/8jswjhnw contains the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile. `template<typename T*>` is illegal and you do not have any partial specializations as you claim.

This works:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    // Lots of functions...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T* obj)
    {
        // We should never be here in the base class.
        assert(false);
    }

    void someFunc(T obj)
    {
        // Call the virtual function.
        virtualHelperFunction(&obj);
    }
};

// Unspecialized template
template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    // ...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T* obj)
    {
        obj->interfaceFunc();
    }
};

// Partial specialisation
template<typename T>
class B<T*> : public A<T*>
{
public:
    // ...

    virtual void virtualHelperFunction(T** obj)
    {
        (*obj)->interfaceFunc();
    }
};

int main() {
    B<SomeObject> instance1;
    instance1.someFunc(SomeObject());

    B<SomeObject*> instance2;
    SomeObject x;
    instance2.someFunc(&x);
}
```